# How to eliminate static background noise?

Tags: c#, naudio, noise

I am using the NAudio BiQuadFilter to play Wav files.  I want to eliminate "static" background noise, those low rumbling sounds that's not human speech. I have created a DSP chain, which passes through the BiQuadFilter. I have feed the filter with a number of different gains and frequencies, while leaving the bandwidth constant. I can lower the static, but the voice gets lowered as well.  How can I isolate just the static noise without affecting the human voice.  If you can just point me in the right direction, that would be great! (I have lost a day researching this.)

I have created 8 bands and set the frequencies to values like 100, 300, 400, 500, 800, 1200, 4800, 9600; Set the gain to values like -6 to -100; kept the Bandwidth at .8.

I also tried using just 1 band and targeting a specific frequency like 1,300 with a gain of -30.

```
Bands = {New EqualizerBand(), New EqualizerBand(), New EqualizerBand(), 
         New EqualizerBand(), New EqualizerBand(), New 
             EqualizerBand(), New EqualizerBand(), New EqualizerBand()}

Bands(0).Bandwidth = 0.8F
 Bands(0).Gain = -6
 Bands(0).Frequency = 100

 Bands(1).Bandwidth = 0.8F
 Bands(1).Gain = -6
 Bands(1).Frequency = 300

 Bands(2).Bandwidth = 0.8F
 Bands(2).Gain = -6
 Bands(2).Frequency = 400

 Bands(3).Bandwidth = 0.8F
 Bands(3).Gain = -6
 Bands(3).Frequency = 500

 Bands(4).Bandwidth = 0.8F
 Bands(4).Gain = -6
 Bands(4).Frequency = 800

 Bands(5).Bandwidth = 0.8F
 Bands(5).Gain = -6
 Bands(5).Frequency = 1200

 Bands(6).Bandwidth = 0.8F
 Bands(6).Gain = -6
 Bands(6).Frequency = 4800

 Bands(7).Bandwidth = 0.8F
 Bands(7).Gain = -6
 Bands(7).Frequency = 9600


  AudioFileReader1 = New AudioFileReader(Me.FilePath)
  Equalizer1 = New EqualizerClass(AudioFileReader1, Bands)
  SpeedControl = New VarispeedSampleProvider(Equalizer1, 100, New 
                 SoundTouchProfile(False, False))
  SpeedControl.PlaybackRate = 1
  VolumeSampleProvider1 = New VolumeSampleProvider(SpeedControl)

Here's the ISampleProvider, which is from this example: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudioWpfDemo/EqualizationDemo 


namespace Equalizer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Basic example of a multi-band eq
    /// uses the same settings for both channels in stereo audio
    /// Call Update after you've updated the bands
    /// Potentially to be added to NAudio in a future version
    /// </summary>
    public class EqualizerClass : ISampleProvider
    {
        private readonly ISampleProvider sourceProvider;
        private readonly EqualizerBand[] bands;
        private readonly BiQuadFilter[,] filters;
        private readonly int channels;
        private readonly int bandCount;
        private bool updated;

        public EqualizerClass(ISampleProvider sourceProvider, EqualizerBand[] bands)
        {
            this.sourceProvider = sourceProvider;
            this.bands = bands;
            channels = sourceProvider.WaveFormat.Channels;
            bandCount = bands.Length;
            filters = new BiQuadFilter[channels, bands.Length];
            CreateFilters();
        }

        private void CreateFilters()
        {
            for (int bandIndex = 0; bandIndex < bandCount; bandIndex++)
            {
                var band = bands[bandIndex];

                for (int n = 0; n < channels; n++)
                {
                    if (filters[n, bandIndex] == null)
                        filters[n, bandIndex] = BiQuadFilter.PeakingEQ(sourceProvider.WaveFormat.SampleRate, band.Frequency, band.Bandwidth, band.Gain);
                    else
                        filters[n, bandIndex].SetPeakingEq(sourceProvider.WaveFormat.SampleRate, band.Frequency, band.Bandwidth, band.Gain);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            updated = true;
            CreateFilters();
        }

        public WaveFormat WaveFormat => sourceProvider.WaveFormat;

        public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int samplesRead = sourceProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);

            if (updated)
            {
                CreateFilters();
                updated = false;
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < samplesRead; n++)
            {
                int ch = n % channels;

                for (int band = 0; band < bandCount; band++)
                {
                    buffer[offset + n] = filters[ch, band].Transform(buffer[offset + n]);
                }
            }
            return samplesRead;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting that when a eliminate the lower frequency ranges (100-500), I should get rid of the "static" background noise and still hear the user's voice.  What actually happens is, both the voice and "static" background noise is lowered.

Comment: Because as [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_frequency) `The voiced speech of a typical adult male will have a fundamental frequency from 85 to 180 Hz, and that of a typical adult female from 165 to 255 Hz.`. Noise filters work based on noise statistics, not through EQ settings. Try playing your audio sample with any audio player that has an equalizer. A quick & dirty approach would be to cut very low frequencies. If you analyze the static you'll probably find it's very low frequency.

Comment: It's worth checking an audio player anyway. The "vocal" or "speech" settings typically lower very low frequencies, boost the middle range etc. The first result when I googled `eq speech` was [this](https://www.behindthemixer.com/eight-tips-for-improving-clarity-in-speech/) which suggests using a high pass filter, boosting the mid range etc

Comment: Thank you both!  I have been playing around with the freq, band width, and gain by changing the values in my code.  I have made progress, but haven't hit the "sweet" spot yet.  Do you know of a free Windows desktop app that would allow me to manipulate these values, possibly on multiple bands, while playing a Wav file?  If not, I will have to write my own, because it's taking too long for me to get a feel for what values will hit my goal.